# Posting jquery datatable data to server in JSON format

Tags: jquery, json, datatables

I know this question has been asked numerous times on SO and on the datatables site, but i cannot get it to work using the solutions provided.

I am building my datatable on the client side and now want to post the client data to my wep api controller in json format.

The client side is working correctly when it comes to adding/deleting rows.
But when i try create my JSON using:

```
    var table = $('#detailTable').DataTable();
var details = JSON.stringify(table.rows().data().toArray());
```

I am getting the following result:

```
[["11046","ABC","bis","123","123",15129]]
```

so basically i am missing column names in my JSON object, thus the web api is failing to pick it up and convert it to:

```
List<ReceiptEntryViewModel> ReceiptDetails
```

So how can i get the datatables to generate a JSON in the following format:

```
[["ItemId":"11046","ItemCode":"ABC","ItemName":"bis","Price":"123","Quantity":"123","Total":15129]]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just want to collect the column names and use them as property names in the JSON, then you can build an array of column names this way :

```
var fieldNames =  [], json = []
table.settings().columns()[0].forEach(function(index) {
  fieldNames.push($(table.column(index).header()).text())  
})
```

I am using `text()` to filter out any HTML. Then do as above but iterate over each row instead, and construct an object literal (JSON item) for each row using the collected `fieldNames` :

```
table.rows().data().toArray().forEach(function(row) {
  var item = {}
  row.forEach(function(content, index) {
     item[fieldNames[index]] = content
  })
  json.push(item)
})
```

Now you have a valid JSON you can `stringify` and send to the server.

Small sample demo -> **http://jsfiddle.net/5j9wgorj/**

Note that this is just an example. If you have larger datasets you should avoid `forEach` and use `for`-loops instead. Also there should be no need for blindly rebuilding an array of header names since you, the developer, know both column names and what you want the properties to be named as beforehand.

---

Update with the solution it ended up to be. The contortions with building a JSON can be avoided if the dataTable itself is prepared for using JSON. Define a `columns` section :

```
var table = $('#example').DataTable({
  columns : [
    {  data : 'myField' }
  ]
})
```

And insert new rows as JSON / literals :

```js
table.row.add({ myField: 'some value' }).draw()
```

Now

```js
JSON.stringify( table.rows().data().toArray() )
```

Will return a valid JSON string that can be passed to the serverscript.

demo -> **http://jsfiddle.net/d07f6uvf/**

Comment: Hi David, thank you for your answer, it looks like it can work, and in my case i will be dealing with max 100 rows, thus dont think there will be an impact on performance. However, i thought there is an inbuilt datatables function (which takes care of the looping already) that can produce a correctly formatted JSON that my wep api can accept

Comment: @JustLearning, unfortunately there is no magic API function that transform your string arrays into JSON. However, **if** you specify a `columns` section for your dataTable **and** insert data as JSON yourself - then the output of `table.rows().data()` will be a valid JSON.  See example ->  **http://jsfiddle.net/ev7yz07L/** So you could say, that if you do it right the first time, you do not need the contortions above :)

Comment: Great, actually the solution in your comment is exactly what i was looking for. Please add to the answer! Thank you

Comment: @JustLearning, have updated with a new example. Thank you accepting the answer.